# React map render key assignation

Tags: reactjs

I know this question might sounds very basic, but I couldn't find any resource to improve my understanding on this.

Please refer to this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-oskar-06d6p?file=/src/App.js), where I have written two ways to assign key to the component rendered inside an iteration.

Component definition

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const { id } = props;
  return <div key={id}>This is a component</div>;
};
```

Component stack definition:

```
const componentStack = [{ Component }, { Component }];
```

Method A:

```
...
{componentStack.map((el) => (
   <el.Component key={a uniquekey} />
))}
...
```

Method B:

```
...
{componentStack.map((el) => (
   <el.Component id={a uniquekey} />
))}
...
```

---

Edited:
I edited my question. I think the Method B should be incorrect. But why is it different from Method A?

---

Edited:
I have added the code snippets for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key is like an id, but for rendering purposes.

> [Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity:

The key attributes is used by react to identify if an element has changed. You can think of it as a commit id. If an object changes and therefore it's id changes, react will re-render it.

Like I said above... a key is for rendering purposes.

Here is an example

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const availableColors = [
  {
    name: "IndianRed",
    value: "#CD5C5C"
  },
  {
    name: "PeachPuff",
    value: "#FFDAB9"
  },
  {
    name: "SlateBlue",
    value: "#6A5ACD"
  },
  {
    name: "DarkSeaGreen",
    value: "#8FBC8B"
  }
];

const Colors = (props) => {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(availableColors);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      const newColors = [...colors];
      shuffle(newColors);
      setColors(newColors);
    }, 2000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="list-group">
        {colors.map((color) => {
          return (
            <li className="list-group-item" key={color.value} style={{ background: color.value }}>
              {color.name}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex],
      array[currentIndex]
    ];
  }

  return array;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Colors />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

When you now take a look at the [`DevTools`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) ( F12 ) you will see the difference in the DOM updates.

## DOM Updates WITHOUT keys

Almost the complete DOM element is replaced.

[image: DOM updates without keys]

## DOM Updates WITH keys

Since the DOM element hasn't changed it is just moved.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. This clearly shows how the DOM works behind the scene. :D

Answer (score 2):

key must be unique. Instead of getDate() use getTime() as below in

```
{componentStack.map((el) => (
        <el.Component key={new Date().getTime()} />
))}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I understand that using time as key is not unique enough as many things could be executed within a millisecond. However, the main question is why method B is incorrect?

Comment: i hope rené-link's answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned, React automatically updates components based on their `key`.

If you have multiple components of the same type you would want to have a unique `key` for every one of then so react can update them separately, otherwise it will update all of them.

So a unique `key` prop is recommended (see the console). The `id` prop does not provide a `key`.

Edit regarding your comment:
the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) (under "Extracting Components with Keys") say that the `key` has to be specified in the component which the `map` function returns, because React accesses the `key` value of each element in the array (that is returned by `map`).

If you pass the `key` value to a child of the component in the array, React will not be able to access it.

FYI you should upload your code directly to SO. This way it is ways easier for people to answer. See [minimal reproducible code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I am agree with you. What if the id prop is then pass to the key prop inside the component (line 5 in the sandbox). Will that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate to all the answers given to my question. However, I think that I asked the question wrongly where the explanations given didn't answer the question in my mind. I am actually wondering why assigning key to the component

```
<el.Component key={"a unique key"} />
```

is different from assigning inside the component using prop

```
const {id} = props;
return <Component key={id} />
```

well I finally realise that assigning the key inside the component is actually assigning to the component itself. Imaging the return clause is a child component and it is just assigning key to that child. So I guess thats is why the code doesn't work.